# How to install the cPickle module?

Tags: python-2.7

I was unable to install the cPickle module using pip:

```
$ pip --version
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
$ pip install cPickle
...
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pickle
```

Attempting installation with pip3 was also unsuccessful:

```
$ pip3 --version
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.4)
$ pip3 install cPickle
...
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement cPickle
```

Could you help me in understanding why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 7):

Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 include the pickle and cPickle modules already.  You do not need to take any extra steps to install them.  You can see a list of currently installed modules by typing

```
help('modules')
```

from a Python prompt.

Comment: I have `Python 2.7.6` and when I type `help('modules')`, I do see `pickle` there but no `cpickle`.

Answer (score 5):

cPickle is by default part of the standard [library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle), but the capital P could be confusing. You should use:

```
import cPickle
```

With the capitial `P`.